# LetsEncrypt certificates not automatically renewed on Windows Server

Tags: plesk, windows, lets-encrypt

I am using LetsEncrypt certificates. When I set up my Windows Server 2016, the LetsEncrypt certificates were renewed automatically but now they run out without being renewed. I must renew them explicitly by Plesk.

Are there some trace files written that I can check the reason?